# how to write a clean up function in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I keep trying to understand how to fix memory leaks in useEffect() but still am having trouble understanding.

The error code says in order to fix the leak I must cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous calls with a clean up function.
This is how my code looks like at the moment.

```
const [dish,setDish] = useState({title:""})

useEffect(()=>{
    fetchDish()
},[dish.title])

const fetchDish = async() => {

    const apiCall = await fetch('https://exampleurl.json')
    const dishes = await apiCall.json()
    setDish(dishes[props.dishID] )

}
```

I am assuming i'm getting a memory leak because I have to destroy my dish object once this unmounts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  componentWillUnmount technique here, as this is a functional component returning from useEffect will cause the same behavior.

For Example:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        fetchDish()
    
        return () => {
          //unmounting code here..
          //in your case 
          setDish({})
        }
   }, [dish.title])
```

Comment: ok so I read that the issue is when my fetch resolves, it executes a setState,  and the problem is , if the component unmounts, and its still fetching, once it resolves, setState fires in a component that isnt mounted... so I have to somehow do a check if the component is mounted..

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should read this [article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov to get a  better understanding of `useEffect`

If you only use the function in your useEffect, then move it inside the useEffect so it doesn't affect the data flow. If you want to re-use the `fetchDish`, then use `useCallback` so it doesn't get called if you don't need it.

If your case is about cleaning the code, then Rishav's answer is correct

```
useEffect( () => {
  subscribe();
  return () => unsubscribe();
}
```

However I think what react is trying to tell you is because of your asyncrhonous call that keep getting called

Try to modify your code to this

```
const [dish,setDish] = useState({title:""})

useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchDish(){

        const apiCall = await fetch('https://exampleurl.json')
        const dishes = await apiCall.json()
        setDish(dishes[props.dishID] )

    }
    fetchDish()
},[])
```